# Create a hashmap dynamically based on a "template" hashmap with clean code

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, collections, hashmap

I have a set of data part of hash tables as follows:

```
    static {
       A_map.put(KEY_1, value0);  
       A_map.put(KEY_2, value1);  
       A_map.put(KEY_3, value2);  
       A_map.put(KEY_4, value3);  
       ...
       A_map.put(KEY_N, valueN);  

       B_map.put(KEY_1, Xvalue0);  
       B_map.put(KEY_2, Xvalue1);  
       B_map.put(KEY_3, Xvalue2);  
       B_map.put(KEY_4, Xvalue3);  
       ...
       B_map.put(KEY_N, XvalueN);  


       C_map.put(KEY_1, Yvalue0);  
       C_map.put(KEY_2, Yvalue1);  
       C_map.put(KEY_3, Yvalue2);  
       C_map.put(KEY_4, Yvalue3);  
       ...
       C_map.put(KEY_N, YvalueN);  

    ....etc  
}
```

I.e. the keys are the same in all hashes but the values are different per hash map.
And I choose which hash map to use at runtime as I have put these hashmaps as values to another hashmap.

But I think this can be more clean. I mean the keys are the same in all hashmaps and only the values should be different based on the hashmap type I choose at run time.
What is a good way to design this cleanly?

Comment: It could be helpful if you described the intended usage more clearly. Assuming that the values all have the same *type*: Is this intended as some sort of "2D HashMap"?

Comment: @Marco13:No. I am testing a server API and I have a specific set of values to send to the server for testing. I wanted a cleaner way than what I have which is all these hashmaps one after the other

Answer (score 2):

I think [Google Guava's Table structure](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Table) fits your use case like a charm. `Table<RowKey, ColumnKey, Value>` is an excellent replacement for a structure like  `Map<RowKey, Map<ColumnKey, Value>>`, which happens to be your exact case.

Conceptually, you could use the name of the hash as the row key (A, B, C, etc. of your example), and your actual key as the column key (KEY_1, KEY_2, KEY_3, etc. of your example).

As you're actually dealing with hash tables, I suggest you use a [`HashBasedTable`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/HashBasedTable.html):

```
Table<String, String, String> table = 
    HashBasedTable.create(M, N); // M maps, N keys per map

table.put(A, KEY_1, value0);  
table.put(A, KEY_2, value1);  
table.put(A, KEY_3, value2);  
table.put(A, KEY_4, value3);  
...
table.put(A, KEY_N, valueN);  

table.put(B, KEY_1, Xvalue0);  
table.put(B, KEY_2, Xvalue1);  
table.put(B, KEY_3, Xvalue2);  
table.put(B, KEY_4, Xvalue3);  
...
table.put(B, KEY_N, XvalueN);  

...
...

table.put(M, KEY_1, Yvalue0);  
table.put(M, KEY_2, Yvalue1);  
table.put(M, KEY_3, Yvalue2);  
table.put(M, KEY_4, Yvalue3);  
...
table.put(M, KEY_N, YvalueN);
```

If you need to get all the mappings for `A`, you can use `Table`'s `row()` method:

```
Map<String, String> mapA = table.row(A);
```

Keep in mind that this structure is optimized for rows, meaning that getting data based *only* on columns would require some iteration.

Answer (score 0):

normally you extract this kind of information in it's own file, an .ini for example. Java has it's own class for that purpose, called [Properties.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html)

If you are trying to internationalize your application (HashMaps with keys and the value in different languages) I suggest you take a look at ResourceBundles

If you really want to stick to code, you could write all your values for each key in an Array and then create the HashMaps automatically by iterating over the array

Edit:

```
String[] keys = {"KEY_1", "KEY_2", "KEY_3"};
String[] values = {
    {"VALUE_1_FOR_KEY_1", "VALUE_2_FOR_KEY_1", "VALUE_3_FOR_KEY_1"},
    {"VALUE_1_FOR_KEY_2", "VALUE_2_FOR_KEY_2", "VALUE_3_FOR_KEY_2"},
    {"VALUE_1_FOR_KEY_3", "VALUE_2_FOR_KEY_3", "VALUE_3_FOR_KEY_3"},
}

int valueToChoose = 1;
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
for(int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    map.put(keys[i], values[i][valueToChoose];
}
```

Comment: Yes I want to do it in code as it is about a test of a feature. But if I iterate over the array how would I pick the proper array?

Comment: The code example does not work but I got what you mean

Comment: Why is valueToChoose initialized to 1?

Comment: yeah i did not test it out, sry

Answer (score 0):

How about using a List instead of a HashMap, since keys are constant and identical in each table.

You could do something like this:

```
enum Keys {
    _1(0), _2(1), _3(2), _4(3);

    private int id = -1;

    private Keys(int i) {
        this.id = i;
    }

    int index() {
        return id;
    }
}

static {
    aList = new ArrayList<String>(Keys.values().length);
    aList.set(Keys._1.index(), "a1");
    aList.set(Keys._2.index(), "a2");
    aList.set(Keys._3.index(), "a3");
    aList.set(Keys._4.index(), "a4");

    bList = new ArrayList<String>(Keys.values().length);
    bList.set(Keys._1.index(), "b1");
    bList.set(Keys._2.index(), "b2");
    bList.set(Keys._3.index(), "b3");
    bList.set(Keys._4.index(), "b4");

}
```

Comment: I need the keys as well.

Comment: If the keys don't change and are known at compile time, you can add their String-representation at the _Keys_ enum in my example by enhancing the construtor.
On the other hand, if the keys are determined during runtime, then I think, the answer of @Magnamag is your best option.